# Unable to create AVD on the latest android version

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

Unable to create AVD on the latest android version.
System Details: Windows 10 Home Premium
32gb ddr4 ram, i7 6700 HQ 2.6 GHz
I click Create Virtual Devices and nothing happens???

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide some more information? You can try Invalidated Caches/Restart in the File tab

Comment: @PatrickKen what info would you mike me to share .... I have closed an opened the android studio and tried. I uninstalled and reinstalled as well as rebooted my system. Still no luck. When I click create virtual devices it says loading images at the bottom That's it. Ihave posted the screenshot.